# When trying to connect to a remote machine with git on windows, using the correct command, there is no response

Tags: git, github

I am using Git Bash to try to connect to GitHub.

I have been using this tutorial: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-git-and-github-on-windows

When I get to the point where I am supposed to enter the following command: 
ssh -T git@github.com

there is just no response. I hit enter, and the cursor just blinks. There isn't an error, but I do not get the welcome message either.

Thank you ahead of time for your help.

Comment: Try adding the `-v` option; it’ll show you some additional info that might help you figure out what’s going on: `ssh -v -T git@github.com`

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I type that in, I also get no response.